# Source that Lulav is a banner representing life

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, sukkot, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

I am reading a Devar Torah by an esteemed Rosh Yeshiva which says "Furthermore, the Midrash  explains that when we lift our lulavim and esrogim on Sukkos, it is essentially a celebration of life. The Midrash illustrates this with an analogy: After a king judges his subjects,  and grants them an additional year of life, they display royal banners in honor of the king, in a demonstration of their gratitude for his judgment. Likewise, the Midrash explains, we presume that Hashem awarded us another year of life on Yom Kippur, and in gratitude for that, we display His royal “flag” – the Four Species – on Sukkos."

Anyone know where this Medresh is? It's certainly not the one in Vayikra Rabbah 30:2.

Comment: try Zohar daf 221 A "בהאי יומא נפקי ישראל ברשימו דמלכא, בתושבחתא דהלילא, עאלין בסכה, אתרוג בשמאלא לולב בימינא, חמאן כלהו דישראל רשימין ברשימין דמלכא קדישא, פתחי ואמרי (תהלים קמד טו) אשרי העם שככה לו, אשרי העם שיהו"ה אלהי"ו"

Comment: Certainly closer. I still don't think that's the one he's talking about.

Comment: I think Eliyahu Ki Tov in Sefer Hatoda'ah ("Book of Our Heritage")alludes to this Midrash.